# remove self reference entity in EntityFramework CodeFirst

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm-light

i defined bellow classes for my EF in wpf for use in mvvm pattern:

```
public class ProductGroup : ViewModelBase
{

    public long ID { get; set; }

    private string _Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set
        {
            if (_Title != value)
            {
                _Title = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
    }

    private byte[] _Icon;
    public byte[] Icon
    {
        get { return _Icon; }
        set
        {
            if (_Icon != value)
            {
                _Icon = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Icon");
            }
        }
    }

    private ProductGroup _Parent;
    public ProductGroup Parent
    {
        get { return _Parent; }
        set
        {
            if (_Parent != value)
            {
                _Parent = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Parent");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ProductGroup> _Childs;
    public ObservableCollection<ProductGroup> Childs
    {
        get { return _Childs; }
        set
        {
            if (_Childs != value)
            {
                _Childs = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Childs");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Product> _Products;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get { return _Products; }
        set
        {
            if (_Products != value)
            {
                _Products = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Products");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Product : ViewModelBase
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    private ProductGroup _Gorup;
    public ProductGroup Gorup
    {
        get { return _Gorup; }
        set
        {
            if (_Gorup != value)
            {
                _Gorup = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Gorup");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

- is my definitions correct ??
- when i want to remove an item from ProductGroups ,The following error occurs:

**An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.**

Note:

- The target ProductGroup is a child of another ProductGroup
- the target ProductGroup has no Child and Product

Comment: what is the inner exception?

Comment: The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.ProductGroups_dbo.ProductGroups_Parent_ID". The conflict occurred in database "dbtest1", table "dbo.ProductGroups", column 'Parent_ID'.
The statement has been terminated.